# html file download from web with URLDownloadToFile creates empty file

Tags: vba, excel, csv, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have a problem which has been discussed in this forum in the past, but although solutions for the specific cases had been proposed, none has been useful for me.
I want to analyze a data table containing recent stock quotes. Precisely this is a Yahoo portfolio. The URL is "https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolio/pf_5/view/view_0". 
If I try to import the portfolio to my worksheet via a web connection, there is no content to be seen in the importation window. This work fine until some time ago, but it seems that Yahoo has changed the code, so that the content cannot be imported anymore. So I cannot use the website in an Excel connection to import my portfolio anymore.

But I can download the file with Chrome without entering credentials (they are already stored in Chrome or in a cookie, don't know) to my download folder as an html-file and when I open it in a browser it will not only show like the original but I can also analyze the downloaded file with Excel. The file length of the file downloaded directly from the browser is 256 kB.
So it seems that the server recognizes how the file is being used and allows storing it, but not analyzing it online.

Now I am trying to write a vba sub that opens the website, downloads the file and then analyzes the stored version.
The analysis part works fine, but I am not able to include a working download in the code. 
When I use the URLDownloadToFile(0, URL1, URL2, 0, 0) method (URL1 is the https address and URL2 is the file name and path), the downloaded file has only 75kB and contains some java code, but there are no data to be seen on the screen when I watch it with the browser and when I try to import the content to Excel, nothing will be imported.
So while URLDownloadToFile may work in most cases, it does not work with the Yahoo portfolio web pages.
My question is:
1) could it help changing the parameters of the function (parameter 1 = pcaller?). But how?
2) is there any other known method available in vba to save a web page without reading it line by line (tried this, too and doesn't work either) ?
These are two methods I tried:

```
  Option Explicit
 'Declarations
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

 'Download Code
Sub download()

Dim done
Dim URL1 As String
Dim URL2 As String

URL1 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolio/pf_5/view/v1"
URL2 = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\pf1 - Yahoo Finance Portfolios.html"

 'This will provide a return value to test.
 'Note the  (   )  around the args
done = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL1, URL2, 0, 0)

 'Test.
If done = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File has been downloaded!"
Else
    MsgBox "File not found!"
End If

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub SaveWebFile()   'this creates an "empty" file!
Dim URL1 As String
Dim URL2 As String

URL1 = "https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolio/pf_5/view/v1"
URL2 = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\pf1 - Yahoo Finance Portfolios.html"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
   With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   .Open "GET", URL1, False
   .send
   Text = .responseText
   End With
 Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(URL2, True)
 objOutputFile.Write Text
 objOutputFile.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for an answer I continued to search for other solutions and found one that works in my case. This is not exactly the answer that I had been looking for but it resolves my problem.
Instead of using the Yahoo portfolio page I am using the Yahoo Finance API now ([see [Alternative to google finance api (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api)).
    The URL

> http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=symbol1[+symbol2+symbol3...]&f=format_code

creates a downloadable comma delimited text file (.csv) which can be stored or evaluated directly in VBA.
[symbol1 ...] are the ticker symbols of the stocks you want to analyze and
{format code} is a series of letters which describe the type of data that you want to see (full list in http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo_finance/)

As I need only the stock symbol and the last price without time, my format code is "sl1".
There is a catch, though, or actually two.
The first (imposed by Yahoo) is that the maximum number of symbols allowed is 200 and that your IP might get blocked if you make too many calls in a short period of time. So real time streaming data can probably not be obtained this way, although the format list includes code for real time data.

The second is given by the **QueryTables.Add** method that I use in the code below, which limits the URL to 255 characters. If the URL string is longer, a runtime error will occur. This means mean that the second limitation will occur before the 200 symbols are reached.

The following code resolves this problem with a loop structure by creating as many calls as necessary to fetch the data for all symbols, where each call uses a URL that is less than 256 characters long.
In my test I use a workbook test.xlsm with two worksheets test and pf1. 
PF1 contains a list of all symbols to fetch in column A starting at Row 3.
The first row in sheet "test" has the starting row of these data in D1 (=3) and the  row of the last symbol in E1.

My sub has an outer loop which repeats the inner loop as often as necessary to fetch all symbols.

The inner loop creates the URL1 for the call, adding as many symbols as possible to the base part of the URL, with the condition that it must stay below 256 characters.Once the URL is complete, the actual pointer to the symbol list is saved as "First" and the data are fetched. Then a new URL is calculated for the next batch of data from the list.

After having fetched all data, row height and column length in the result sheet are reset, because I noticed that they get changed during the operation (don't know why).

I have also noticed that some of the price values, which come in the US decimal format (with decimal "dot") may lose the dot during the query. Not sure if this is due to my number format (european, with "comma") or to some problem with the query itself. Ideally my number format should not have any influence as the downloaded data should be all TEXT. Anyway this makes it necessary to correct eventual outliers using a list of approximate price values for all symbols. This correction is not included in this sub.

```
Sub Import_CSV_File_From_URL()

Dim URL1 As String
Dim URL As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim First As Long
Dim Last As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim URLlen As Long
Dim NxtLen As Long
Dim destCell As Range
Dim qt As QueryTable


Set ws = ActiveSheet

URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="
First = ws.Range("D1")
Last = ws.Range("E1")
i = First

Do While i < Last                           'loop through all symbols

    ws.Range("A" & First & ":Z1000").Clear  'clear all cells otherwise query inserts new columns.
    Set destCell = Worksheets("test").Range("A" & First)

    URL1 = URL
    For i = First To Last
        If i > First Then
            URL1 = URL1 & "+"
        End If
        URL1 = URL1 & Worksheets("pf1").Range("A" & i)                      'add up to 200 symbols but
        If Len(URL1) > 249 - Len(Worksheets("pf1").Range("A" & i + 1)) Then 'len(URL1) cannot be >255!!
            First = i + 1       'save index for next batch of symbols
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    URL1 = URL1 & "&f=sl1"         'format "sl1": get symbol & last Trade for these tickers

    With destCell.Parent.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & URL1, Destination:=destCell)
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    For Each qt In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
        If qt.Refreshing Then qt.CancelRefresh
        qt.Delete                                       'delete internal query tables
    Next    

Loop        'add next batch of symbols

ws.Range("A:B").ColumnWidth = 8
For i = 3 To Last
    ws.Rows(i).RowHeight = 15
Next i
End Sub
```